# Applying a calendar function directly into a tibble

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

Is a way to apply `create_calendar`  directly into a tibble? I found a work around which is to create a "Calendar" df based off the other data set `Calendar <- create_calendar(df$Date)` and then bind the columns together `df <- left_join(df, Calendar, by = "Date")` but would like to understand how to apply it directly into a df.

Thanks!

Current approach:

```
#Create Calendar Function
create_calendar = function(dates) {

#Create a sequence of dates from the minimum to the maximum date in the input column
  Dates = seq(min(dates), max(dates), by="days")
  
#Convert the dates to a tibble and add additional columns
  Calendar = as_tibble(Dates) %>%
    rename(Date = value) %>%
    mutate(
      DateNo = day(Date),
      NameDay = wday(Date,label = TRUE, abbr=FALSE),
      NameDayShort = wday(Date,label = TRUE),
      DayinWeek = wday(Date),
      MonthNo = month(Date),
      NameMonth = month(Date, label = TRUE, abbr=FALSE),
      NameMonthShort = month(Date, label = TRUE),
      Week = week(Date),
      Year = year(Date),
      Quarter = quarter(Date, with_year = F, fiscal_start = 7)) %>% 

#Month number for the Australian financial year
  Calendar <- Calendar %>%
    mutate(AFYMonth = case_when(
      NameMonthShort == "Jul" ~ 1
      NameMonthShort == "Aug" ~ 2,
      NameMonthShort == "Sep" ~ 3,
      NameMonthShort == "Oct" ~ 4,
      NameMonthShort == "Nov" ~ 5,
      NameMonthShort == "Dec" ~ 6,
      NameMonthShort == "Jan" ~ 7,
      NameMonthShort == "Feb" ~ 8,
      NameMonthShort == "Mar" ~ 9,
      NameMonthShort == "Apr" ~ 10,
      NameMonthShort == "May" ~ 11,
      NameMonthShort == "Jun" ~ 12,
    ))
  
#Format the week column as %V
  Calendar$Week <- format(Calendar$Date, format = "%V")
  
  return(Calendar)
}

#Read function and apply to current df [Missing Step]
df <- df %>%
  mutate(Calendar = create_calendar(Date))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can the tidyverse operator `{{}}`, it allows to reference a column name inside a tidyverse function.

### Function

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)


create_calendar <- function(df,dt_var) {
  

  #Convert the dates to a tibble and add additional columns
  Calendar <-
    df %>% 
    mutate(
      DateNo = day({{dt_var}}),
      NameDay = wday({{dt_var}},label = TRUE, abbr=FALSE),
      NameDayShort = wday({{dt_var}},label = TRUE),
      DayinWeek = wday({{dt_var}}),
      MonthNo = month({{dt_var}}),
      NameMonth = month({{dt_var}}, label = TRUE, abbr=FALSE),
      NameMonthShort = month({{dt_var}}, label = TRUE),
      Week = week({{dt_var}}),
      Year = year({{dt_var}}),
      Quarter = quarter({{dt_var}}, with_year = F, fiscal_start = 7)) 
    
    #Month number for the Australian financial year
    Calendar <- 
      Calendar %>%
      mutate(AFYMonth = case_when(
        NameMonthShort == "Aug" ~ 1,
        NameMonthShort == "Sep" ~ 2,
        NameMonthShort == "Oct" ~ 3,
        NameMonthShort == "Nov" ~ 4,
        NameMonthShort == "Dec" ~ 5,
        NameMonthShort == "Jan" ~ 6,
        NameMonthShort == "Feb" ~ 7,
        NameMonthShort == "Mar" ~ 8,
        NameMonthShort == "Apr" ~ 9,
        NameMonthShort == "May" ~ 10,
        NameMonthShort == "Jun" ~ 11,
        NameMonthShort == "Jul" ~ 12
      ))
    
    #Format the week column as %V
    Calendar$Week <- format(Calendar$Date, format = "%V")
    
    return(Calendar)
}
```

### Example

```
df <- data.frame(dt = lubridate::dmy("01/01/01"))

create_calendar(df,dt)
```